# Can row grand totals be split and aggregated based on a column dimension in excel pivot table?

Tags: excel, pivot

I want to show the row grand total like this:

[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: With your comment below, there's no where near enough information on this to begin to help.  The above isn't a pivot table, but you want to do something with one? Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and edit your post with more information, including what you have tried.  The above is not clear *at all*.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data has `Jan` in `b2`, you can use `SumIf()`:

In the cell under `1` under `Grand Total`, use

`=SUMIF($B$3:$G$3,H$3,$B$4:$G$4)`

`B3:G3` is the `1,2,3,1,2,3` range.
`H3` is the `1` under `Grand Total`
`B4:G4` is the blanks from the cell right of `sale1` to the `3` in Feb.

Comment: the first problem the pivot table default grand total does not split to 1,2,3 , they just sum Jan(1,2,3)+Feb(1,2,3).